# WordPress and MediaWiki sitemap

Tags: wordpress, sitemap, mediawiki

I'm planning to make a WordPress site and include, also, a wiki, using MediaWiki.
I know how to generate WP and MW sitemaps. Anyway, I think I need to merge the two sitemaps in some way. Am I right? How can I do this?

Comment: Kinda right, you don't need to merge both sitemaps. Simply have a sitemap for the sitemaps. That way Google can discover both sitemaps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to merge the sitemaps, you can list multiple sitemaps your *robots.txt* file:

```
Sitemap: http://example.com/first_sitemap.xml
Sitemap: http://example.com/second_sitemap.xml
```

You can also submit multiple sitemaps to Google via [Google Webmaster Tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools).